# How to contact WordPress support regarding registration problem of new account?

Tags: wordpress.com, gravatar

I'd like to create a [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) for my other e-mail account, however when creating an account the site is showing the error:

> Use a different email address. This email provider blocks some of our emails.

I don't want to change the e-mail provider as the only reason that I'm creating the account is to associate the Gravatar image. The e-mail provider is receiving the messages.

How is it possible to contact WordPress via on-line form or e-mail to inform about the problem, without having the account (because of the registration issue)?

There is [Support page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/), but it seems not helpful. For example Account Recovery page requires validation of keys and other pages point to help pages or forum (where people won't have possibility to unlock the blockage).